# Is there an easy way to log the content of the console to a web page?

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

Currently, I develop with java / spring-boot / log4j2 , and as much as I have searched I have not seen anything interesting to log directly to a web page in real-time (something like swagger style with requests, which is by configuration without having to write code) .

Do you know anything?

Answer (score 1):

You need Javascript to modify the DOM of a webpage, not Java.

You could use Spring to send Server-Sent-Events (SSE) to a frontend JS library, or host a WebSocket or other REST API on some web *server* and use AJAX to issue requests, upon which the DOM is modified as part of a response, but this really has nothing to do with Java/Spring/log4j

If you want a packaged distribution of Spring w/ some Javascript framework, JHipster is a popular option.

Comment: I am aware that you need js for that sort of thing. My question was more focused on if there was some kind of configuration with slf4j or spring-boot to do it (or some other framework) like swagger(https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api) does for example.

Comment: The Swagger UI HTML page is completely written in HTML/CSS/JS and uses AJAX to issue requests, so I dont understand your question. The only reason Spring is part of the article is that the Java annotations are parsed and create a `swagger.json` file that the Swagger UI Javascript knows how to parse and render. That file could be hand-written or machine-generated, so Java really is an implementation detail and is not responsible for doing more than hosting a webserver